# Gas estimation fails when deplying contract through Remix, jsonrpc allowance

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I've deployed the NFT mint contract on Sepolia without issues. Same contract on Polygon. No issues. Tried Remix VM Shanghai, no issues.

Deploying to mainnet gives error "Gas estimation failed" ... exact message:
`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"gas required exceeds allowance (126261)","id":1001518708440107}`

Clicking "Send Transaction" after that, opens a Confirm transaction window with estimated fees and gas... and clicking Confirm opens Metamask which in turn doesn't gives any errors... confirming in Metamask ends with failed transaction and burned all Eth used for deploy.

I have no clue what could be the issue... any ideas?

Tried deploying from other addresses, tried changing RPC in Metamask (from Infura to Ankr).. also tried deploying to Remix VM mainnet fork (which also works)... just deploying to mainnet doesn't.

[Tenderly debug of failed deploy](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/mainnet/0x043495b22c05079e153e63df1ed833cec467c78267c2f0a75d977ed7e443190d?trace=0.0.0.0)